# how to replace abcd/FR/efgh by xxxx/FR/xxxx

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this varchar: abcd/FR/efgh and I want to replace it by xxxx/FR/xxxx 
ex:

```
abcd/FR/efgh => xxxx/FR/xxxx
dijfh/BE/edodfgh => xxxxx/BE/xxxxxxx
/BE/as => /BE/as
```

any idea how I can do this in oracle ?

Comment: which letters should be replaced by 'x'?

Answer (score 1):

By using several string functions like [`rpad`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions140.htm), [`instr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564), [`substr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) and [`length`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm):

```
select 
  case 
    when s not like '%_/%/_%' then s
    else 
      rpad('x', instr(s, '/', 1, 1) - 1, 'x') 
      || '/' || 
      substr(s, instr(s, '/', 1, 1) + 1, instr(s, '/', 1, 2) - instr(s, '/', 1, 1) - 1)
      || '/' ||
      rpad('x', length(s) - instr(s, '/', 1, 2), 'x') 
  end s  
from tablename
```

Replace `s` with your column's name.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ba1c181befe27def445ccfdfc70b7606).
Rsults:

```
> | S                |
> | :--------------- |
> | xxxx/FR/xxxx     |
> | xxxxx/BE/xxxxxxx |
> | /BE/as           |
```